# PythonPDF: FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, jinja2, pdf-generation, pdf-form

I am getting the below error trace when I am using PDFJinja's example for filling form fields in an existing PDF file.

**Code Snippet:**

```
        dir_name = os.path.dirname("P:\\Project\\pdfjinja_services\\resources\\sample.pdf")
        template_pdf_file = os.path.join(dir_name, 'sample.pdf')
        template_pdf = PdfJinja(template_pdf_file, current_app.jinja_env)
        print(type(template_pdf))
        rendered_pdf = template_pdf({
            'firstName': 'Faye',
            'lastName': 'Valentine'   
        })
        output_file = os.path.join(dir_name, 'output.pdf')
        rendered_pdf.write(open(output_file, 'wb'))
```

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "P:\Professional\Python\CR\workspace\workspace-local\myplaybook\pdf_pdfjinja.py", line 10, in
rendered_pdf = template_pdf({
File "P:\Professional\Python\Softwares\python-3.9.6\lib\site-packages\pdfjinja.py", line 240, in call
filled = PdfFileReader(self.exec_pdftk(self.rendered))
File "P:\Professional\Python\Softwares\python-3.9.6\lib\site-packages\pdfjinja.py", line 212, in exec_pdftk
p = Popen(args, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
File "P:\Professional\Python\Softwares\python-3.9.6\lib\subprocess.py", line 951, in init
self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
File "P:\Professional\Python\Softwares\python-3.9.6\lib\subprocess.py", line 1420, in _execute_child
hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

I am using python-3.9.6 and PDFJinja-1.1.0.
Please let me know if I am missing any other dependencies.

Comment: Please provide a  minimal self-contained example that demonstrate the problem.  The key question is probably what args is in the call `p = Popen(args, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)`.  And my guess is that you are missing the binary or it's not in your search path.

Comment: Thanks for replying @AllanWind. When I debug, I can see the below values are passed for the attribute args-   ['pdftk', 'P:/Project/pdfjinja_services/resources\\sample.pdf', 'fill_form', '-', 'output', '-', 'dont_ask', 'flatten']. The above code example is I have taken from [https://github.com/rammie/pdfjinja/blob/master/examples/example.py](https://github.com/rammie/pdfjinja/blob/master/examples/example.py) for my POC.

Comment: Further analysis, It seems I don't have pdftk tool. which is kind of dependency for pdfjinja. I will try to install and verify.

Comment: I have tried installing  [pdftk](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-server/) and tested. but still getting the same error.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Community I have trimmed the code to make it easier to view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a binary (per update pdftk), or the binary is not in your search path.

Comment: yes @Allan Wind. After adding the pdftk in the environment path, I am able to execute the above code without an issue. Thanks.